# Usage of the terms Raman, Stokes and anti-Stokes scattering

Tags: optics, terminology, raman-spectroscopy

I am confused over the correct usage of the terminology for ["Raman scattering"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering), "Stokes scattering", "anti-Stokes scattering", or even "Stokes-Raman scattering" and "anti-Stokes-Raman scattering".

Is Raman scattering the superior term for Stokes and anti-Stokes scattering? Or do they essentially mean the same, and people are just too lazy to always write "anti-Stokes-Raman scattering"?

Could you post an explanation and maybe examples for the correct usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the link you provided, Raman scattering is any scattering that changes the frequency/wavlength/energy of the light by transfer of energy to or from the matter that scatters it. If the matter absorbs energy it is called Stokes Raman scattering (sometimes shortened to just Stokes scattering). If the matter loses energy it is called anti-Stokes Raman scattering (sometimes shortened to just anti-Stokes scattering). In many cases, the matter is mostly in a ground state and cannot lose energy. Hence no anti-Stokes Raman scattering can occur. For this reason, Raman scattering in some contexts implies Stokes Raman scattering, even though it is not stated explicitly.

Comment: Small comment:  in Raman scattering from molecules, the energy is transferred to vibrations of the molecule.  In Raman scattering from solids, the energy is transferred to optical phonons.  When energy is transferred to acoustic phonons, the phenomenon is called *Brillouin scattering*.

Comment: Okay, so Raman scattering is the superior term, and the only two possibilities for a Raman scattering process are stokes scattering and anti-stokes scattering? Or are there any other possibilites?

Comment: @garyp Yes, and Brillouin scattering can also be Stokes or anti-Stokes, depending on whether the energy is lost and or gained. So technically, Stokes scattering could refer to either Stokes Raman scattering or Stokes Brillouin scattering.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: With the above definitions, Brillouin scattering would only be a special case of Raman scattering (Raman scattering in solids)!? However, in order not to spread confusion, one would always speak about Raman scattering when treating liquids or gases and about Brillouin scattering when treating solids?

Comment: @Timitry I think there might be different conventions here. I think in some fields, Brillouin scattering is seen as a type of Raman scattering, while in others they are seen as separate.